# Nokia Issue Background Service with LocationManager

Tags: java, android, service, background, locationmanager

I am developing android application using background service with a feature GPS location based with LocationManager class. My code is runnning successfully on most phones but with Nokia phones and more particularly with Nokia Android 9.0 the background service is runnning normally but, after about 20 minutes the LocationListener stops without provide any GPS position although the background service continue to run. It seems that onLocationChanged() method stops suddently without Exception.

I saw there are similar issues on other feature with Nokia but I did not found any solution.

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)
this._activity.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

// Define a listener that responds to location updates
locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        JSONObject coords = new JSONObject();

        try {
            json.put("latitude",location.getLatitude());
            json.put("longitude",location.getLongitude());
            json.put("altitude",location.getAltitude());
            json.put("bearing",location.getBearing());
            json.put("speed",location.getSpeed());
            json.put("provider",location.getProvider());

            coords.put("coords",json);

            Log.d(TAG,"onLocationChanged "+coords.toString());            
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG,"onLocationChanged JSONException "+e.getMessage());               
        }

    }
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){
        Log.d(TAG,"onLocationChanged status changed : "+provider+ " status="+status);
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.d(TAG,"onLocationChanged provider enabled "+provider);
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Log.d(TAG,"onLocationChanged provider disabled "+provider);
    }
};
```

I would appreciate any help in order to solve that issue or to find a workaround. Thank you.

Comment: what other android version did you checked?

Comment: SOunds like background location limits  https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits

Comment: For example: with Samsung Android 7.0, 8.0, 8.1 and Nokia 8.1 I do not have any problems. Curiously and at least with Nokia phones Android 9.0, there is a timeout after 20 minutes the method onLocationChanged() is not called again

Answer (score 0):

After installing Nokia patch 00WW_3_51F the issue was solved